# Cast Protocol<> Any to String (or others)

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a class called **User()**

```
class User {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var id: String?
    var identification_number: String?
    var phone_number: NSMutableArray?    
    var user_group: String?
    var date: NSDate?
}
```

I want to get all of the variables in the class and their respective values. I am trying to use **Mirror** in this case.

```
func updateProfile(user: User) {

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: user)

    for child in mirror.children {
        print("\(child.label!), \(child.value)")
    }

}
```

My question is, how can I convert `child.value` to any other datatype, say `String` ?
I only got to find out that child.value belongs to the **`Protocol 'Any'`**

Comment: I am not understanding why `child.value is String` is always `false`. Even when the `child` does refer a `String` property (like `name`) which I have populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a protocol for extending `Optional<Any>` type to return it's non-optional-value:

```
private protocol AnyOptional {
    var objectValue: Any? { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
    var objectValue: Any? {
        switch self {
        case .None:
            return nil
        case .Some(_):
            return self! as Any
        }
    }
}
```

Thereafter you can use `AnyOptional` protocol as a type, and cast `Any?` objects to `AnyOptional`, thereafter allowing us to make use of the `.objectValue` property of `AnyOptional`

```
class User {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var id: String = "Default ID" // Lets try also with one non-optional
    var identification_number: String?
    var phone_number: NSMutableArray?
    var user_group: String?
    var date: NSDate?
}

var myUser = User()
myUser.name = "John"
myUser.phone_number = ["+44", "701 23 45 67"]

func updateProfile(user: User) {

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: user)

    for child in mirror.children {
        let value : Any = (child.value as? AnyOptional)?.objectValue ?? child.value

        switch(value) {
        case let obj as String: print("String item: User.\(child.label!) = " + obj)
        case let obj as NSMutableArray: print("NSMutableArray item: User.\(child.label!) = \(obj)")
        case let obj as NSDate: print("NSDate item: User.\(child.label!) = \(obj)")
        case _ : print("Non-initialized optional item: User.\(child.label!) = \(value)")
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields the following output

```
updateProfile(myUser)

/*
String item: User.name = John
Non-initialized optional item: User.email = nil
String item: User.id = Default ID
Non-initialized optional item: User.identification_number = nil
NSMutableArray item: User.phone_number = (
    "+44",
    "701 23 45 67"
)
Non-initialized optional item: User.user_group = nil
Non-initialized optional item: User.date = nil       */
```

The benefit of using this solution is that it will "unwrap" optional non-nil values of `child.value` (without the `"Optional(...)"` padding) *as well* as values of `child.value` that are *not* optional, without the need of separate "unwrapping" for the two cases. In the `switch` case above, you can handle whatever non-nil property of the `User` object that you need to work with, not just as `String` but any of the types in your `User` class. The `obj` property in the `switch` case will be of the non-optional type of each of the non-nil properties of your class. The default case corresponds to optionals with value `nil` (not assigned).

Comment: hey @dfri wonderful solution here! thanks! i was wondering, from your `switch(value)` here, how and where do I get the `obj`? and would it be possible to cast it to `AnyObject`?

Comment: @munfai Happy to help. The `... let obj as ...` in the switch cases assigns `value` to immutable `obj` as the type `... as Type`, _if possible_. Hence, within each case, if you enter it, `obj` will be an immutable of the type the case covers (downcast from `Any`). Regarding you 2nd question: you _could_ try to cast `Any` to `AnyObject`, but I suggest you stick to using one of them (or none, if preferable..). `AnyObject` can only hold only class types (hence cannot hold _native_ swift value types `String`, `Int` and so on), whereas `Any` can hold class as well as value types.

Answer (score 3):

`child.value` has the `Any` type. Casting from `Any` to an optional poses some problems, fortunately Sandy Chapman gave a very nice solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060818/is-it-possible-to-cast-any-to-an-optional).

With his function, the code would look like this:

```
func castToOptional<T>(x: Any) -> T? {
    return Mirror(reflecting: x).descendant("Some") as? T
}

func updateProfile(user: User) {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: user)
    for child in mirror.children {
        print("\(child.label!), \(child.value)")
        if let stringVal = castToOptional(child.value) as String? {
            print("Unwrapped a string: \(stringVal)")
        } else if let stringVal = child.value as? String {
            print("Found a non-optional string: \(stringVal)")
        }
    }
}
```

So if you're looking for strings, you need to look for both optional and non-optional ones. This applies to all types you need to check.

Comment: The solution looks perfectly valid. However in Playground the execution never enter the `IF` block. Of course I populated the instance `let user = User()
user.name = "1"`
Any clue?

Comment: Maybe there are no strings in `child.value`?

Comment: I assigned a proper `String` value to the `name` property.

Comment: On the other hand this code
`let any: Any? = "Hello world";
if let stringValue = any as? String {
    print(stringValue)
} else {
    print("No string found")
}`
 does work as expected and the output is "Hello world".

Comment: @appzYourLife this drove me also crazy, so I did some digging on the internet, and found the solution to casting `Any` to an `Optional`, ironically or not, on SO :). I updated my answer with the finding.