# Casting to generic optional in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

I'm fiddling around with generics in Swift and hit something I can't figure out: If I cast a value into the type of a generic parameter, the cast is not performed. If I try the same with static types, it works.

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    init?() {
        if let _ = 4 as? T {
            println("should work")
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int?>() {
    println("not called")
}

if let _ = 4 as? Int? {
    println("works")
}
```

Can anybody explain this behavior? Shouldn't be both cases equivalent?

### Update

The above example is simplified to the max. The following example illustrates the need for a cast a little better

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    init?(v: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if let _ = v["k"] as? T? {
            print("should work")
        } else {
            print("does not")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int?>(v: ["k": 4]) {
    print("not called")
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int>(v: ["k": 4]) {
    print("called")
}
```

### 2nd Update

After @matt made me learn about `AnyObject` and `Any` and @Darko pointed out in his comments how dictionaries make my example too complicated, here's my next refinement

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    private var value: T!

    init?<U>(param: U) {
        if let casted = param as? T {
            value = casted
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


if let _ = SomeClass<Int?>(param: Int(4)) {
    println("not called")
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int>(param: Int(4)) {
    println("called")
}

if let _ = Int(4) as? Int? {
    println("works")
}

if let _ = (Int(4) as Any) as? Int? {
    println("Cannot downcast from Any to a more optional type 'Int?'")
}
```

I tried using `init?(param: Any)` before, but that yields the same problem illustrated in the last `if` which is [discussed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type).

So all it comes down to: Has anyone really been far as to ever cast anything to a generic optional type? In any case? I'm happy to accept any working example.

Comment: I'm also stuck on this; feels like a hole in the language.  Did you ever get a resolution?

Comment: I just tried the third example in an Xcode 8.2.1 project again (Playgrounds are currently broken for me) and it runs as expected, printing `not called` and `called`. I could also change `T!` to `T`.

Answer (score 3):

This is really not about generics at all; it's about AnyObject (and how casting works). Consider:

```
    let d = ["k":1]
    let ok = d["k"] is Int?
    print (ok) // true

    // but:

    let d2 = d as [String:AnyObject]
    let ok2 = d2["k"] is Int?
    print (ok2) // false, though "is Int" succeeds
```

Since your initializer casts the dictionary up to `[String:AnyObject]` you are in this same boat.

Comment: So why does 'let ok2 = d2["k"] is Int' succeed? dict adds always the optional to the return value and apart from that Int is not a class type like AnyObject.

Comment: Because when you say "is", an Optional gets special treatment; we pretend you posed to the question "is" to the thing-inside-the-optional. So now we're asking "Can this AnyObject be cast down to an Int" - and it can, because it is an NSNumber. But an AnyObject cannot be cast down to an `Optional<Int>`.

Comment: In other words, once you realize that the generic in the original question is a complete red herring, everything happening here is covered by my book's discussion of casting (http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting) and of AnyObject (http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_anyobject).

Comment: Ok, so the intermediate step over NSNumber was the missing link to understanding. I just tried to `let d : [String: Int64] = ["k":1]` and you are right, the cast to `[String: AnyObject]` does not work anymore, because NSNumber is not compatible with Int64. But why AnyObject can not be cast down to Optional<Int>? It could assume Optional<NSNumber>. You wrote:  "Because when you say "is", an Optional gets special treatment; we pretend you posed to the question "is" to the thing-inside-the-optional." It's somehow inconsistent. (can not find the explanation in your book)

Comment: I don't see why it's inconsistent. `Optional<NSNumber>` is not a class type. It is not bridged to Objective-C. You cannot cast an `Int?` or an `NSNumber?` _up_ to AnyObject, so there's no chance in the world that you'd ever be able to cast an AnyObject _down_ to either of those things. What surprises me is that the compiler lets you pose the question at all.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the explanation, it's logical. The Obj-C bridge breaks many consistencies in the language in my opinion. E.g. there is no implcit casting in Swift - but it's their for the Obj-C Bridge. Integers are casted to NSNumber - except Int64. var arr = ["text", 2] is inferred as NSDictionary, but it should be NSMutableDictionary when "var" is used. etc... (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation! You made me aware of the difference between `Any` and `AnyObject` (unfortunately `Any` seems to have different problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type). However I still don't understand why my first example does not work, which is not about `AnyObject`..or is it?

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected now - in Playgrounds as well as in projects. Retested in Swift 5.4:

```swift
class SomeClass<T> {
    private var value: T

    init?<U>(param: U) {
        if let casted = param as? T {
            value = casted
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


if let _ = SomeClass<Int?>(param: Int(4)) {
    print("called")
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int>(param: Int(4)) {
    print("called")
}
```

which prints `called` two times as expected.

Comment: Side note: My previous reply from 2017 that it's working as expected got deleted. Not sure why. The question just received another upvote, so I thought it might be worth sharing the current state of things.

Answer (score 0):

As far I can see the goal of your updated code is to find out if the passed parameter (the value of the dict) is of type T. So you are mis-using the as? cast to check the type. What you actually want is the "is" operator.

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    init?(v: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if v["k"] is T {
            print("called if AnyObject is of type T")
        } else {
            print("called if AnyObject is not of type T")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int>(v: ["k": 4]) {
    print("called")
}

if let _ = SomeClass<Int?>(v: ["k": 4]) {
    print("not called")
}
```