# What's the difference between (as! SKView?) and (as? SKView)

Tags: swift

I have just built a SpriteKit demo app. 
I don't under the code below

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        ...
    }
```

What does (self.view as! SKView?)  meaning?
Why don't they just write code like this:

```
if let view = self.view as? SKView {
        ...
    }
```

What's the difference?
Thanks a lot！

Comment: The first syntax (*forced unwrapping* an optional to an optional) is a contradiction in terms and shouldn't be used at all. I wish the compiler was throwing an error when being used in an optional binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting to generic optional in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080420/casting-to-generic-optional-in-swift)

Comment: @Eric Has your question been answered?

Comment: I get these codes in SpriteKit default demo created by Xcode 8.2.  I think the developer use  ( as! )  because he want to express that  (self.view）is already set to a SKView instance and will never be nil. In the meanwhile, he  wants to use ( if  let )  syntax, so he need a optional type (SKView?). Maybe it is just a habit and not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Case 1

`self.view` is force cast to `SKView?` (a.k.a. `Optional<SKView>`). If this cast fails (when `self.view` isn't actually an `SKView?`), then the program will crash to prevent going into an inconsistent state.

The resulting `SKView?` is then safely unwrapped and assigned to `view` if it's not `nil`, otherwise the `else` case is executed, if there is one.

## Case 2

`self.view` is safely cast to `SKView`. The result of this expression is a `SKView`. It will have a valid value (if the cast was possible), or `nil` if the cast wasn't possible. Unlike the first case, it won't crash.

The resulting `SKView?` is then safely unwrapped and assigned to `view` if it's not `nil`, otherwise the `else` case is executed, if there is one.

Comment: It will. http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5853c53e6749731cc79801b0 @AppzYourLife

Comment: Thanks，Alexander. Though I still not quite understand the meaning of code in the demo. Maybe it is just a syntax and do not need pay much attention.

Comment: @Eric I mean, I gave explanations exactly addressing the particular example in mind. Perhaps try asking me follow up questions, and I'll try to address the confusion. It's not just syntax, the two options are semantically different. It's definitely important to know the difference

Answer (score 0):

```
if let view = self.view as? SKView { ... }
```

This means that if the view can be cast to SKView, then do it, otherwise don't do it. This is safe as it won't crash the program and is recommended. That's what the question mark means. Can it be cast as an SKView?

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? { ... }
```

This really shouldn't be used at all. You're saying that the view should be cast by force to an optional SKView that will work if SKView can be unwrapped. Like another user stated, it's repetitive and shouldn't be used even if it won't give you an error.