# Swift dynamically cast nil to optional

Tags: swift

The following code works:

```
nil as! String?
"muffin" as! String?
```

Therefore I also expect this to work:

```
var magicArray: [Any?] = ["Muffin", nil, 3]

class Box<T> {

    var index: Int

    init(index: Int){
        self.index = index
    }

    func get() -> T {
        return magicArray[index] as! T //crash
    }

}
```

But neither

```
let box = Box<String?>(index: 0)
box.get()
```

nor

```
let box = Box<String?>(index: 1)
box.get()
```

works as expected. The program crashes at the cast in `get()`. This however works:

```
let box = Box<Int>(index: 2)
box.get()
```

I need to be able to cast a `Any?` value to `T` inside my class where `T` can be any type, including optionals. The `Any?` actually comes from an array of `Any?` so there is no other way of verifying it’s of the correct type `T`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Adam It’s needed for an ORM library. Just believe me, I need it.

Comment: Saying "Any" with regard to a generic seems to completely miss the point of generics.

Comment: @matt I’ve updated my answer to add more context. Am I really missing the point of generics?

Comment: The question title should be something around "How to cast any? to optional". [This should give you a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/32780793#32780793)

Comment: @LopSae Thanks for your help. Actually I think now my design is simply bad, I’ll try to find a way so that I don’t have to deal with `[Any?]` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a generic wrapper, this should work for you:

```
final class Wrapper<T> {
    final let wrappedValue: T
    init(theValue: T) {
        wrappedValue = theValue
    }
}
```

You can replace `let` with `var` to make it mutable.

Edit:

This is the code I used to test it on a playground.

```
var s : Any?

s = "some string"

let w = Wrapper(theValue: s)

w.wrappedValue

let int = 3

let w2 = Wrapper(theValue: int)

w2.wrappedValue

w2.wrappedValue = 3

let array : [Any?] = [s, int, nil, "abc", NSObject()]

for obj in array {
    let wrapper = Wrapper(theValue: obj)
}
```

Comment: I can’t see any cast from `Any?` to `T`. I don’t just need a wrapper, I need a wrapper that can cast `Any?` values to `T`.

Comment: You haven't specified your requirements. Why do you need to cast from `Any?` to `T` ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear from my example. I need to be able to cast a `Any?` value to `T` inside my class where `T` can be any type, including optionals. Explaining why I’ve got a `Any?` value is way to complicated.

Comment: The `Any?` comes from an array of `Any?` so there is no other way of verifying it’s of the correct type `T`.

Comment: The wrapper will work with an array of `Any?` and use the right type for each of them. I just tested it with strings, ints, optional or not, and also with an array of `Any?`. Worked perfectly. Not sure if I understand why you need to cast it to some other type. In my class, `T` is a generic type. It is determined when the wrapper object is constructed and the same type is returned.

Comment: Sure. Edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, I was too unclear again. The wrapper get’s an `Any?` value and then **casts this value on request**. The wrapper is given a `Any?` and gives the value back as `T`, if he is request to do so.  That all happens at run time. That’s the way I need to do it. If my explanation is still to vague I will try to provide update my answer to provide a more realistic example why I need this.

Comment: I’ve updated my question, I hope it’s now more clear. Anyways thanks for trying to help so far.

Comment: I have seen your edit. It is not possible and for me, it doesn't make sense. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: How do you know it’s not possible? Is there any Swift reference describing this? Otherwise it’s more likely to be a bug in Swift itself.

Comment: Not possible because you are trying to cast different values to a single type. How would you expect it to work. You want `String` to magically convert into `Int` or `UIView`? Not gonna happen.

Comment: I would not expect this too work if that were not that two lines of code at the beginning of my question that do actually work.

Comment: They do, because both `nil` and `"muffin"` are proper `String?` values. If you try `"muffin" as! UIView?`, it will crash.

Comment: But if I store a `String` in an `Any?` variable it becomes an invalid `String?` value, or what are you trying to tell me? The problem is Swift itself. It does not expect `T` to be an optional and therefore does not do an automatic conversion to the optional, because `String` is as you said not `Optional<String>`. (If it expects an optional is seems to try to do a conversion.)