# Realm: Partially update

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using realm in my Swift project and I'm having issues partially updating objects.

The problem is that I have an object that contains information from the server **plus** user generated informations. In my case it is a *Topic* that can be either visible or hidden by default, but the user can change the visibility value.

When I launch my app for the first time I call my server API to fetch the information to create a *Topic* object: it has as `visibility` value `undefined`. Then the user makes a choice and set the `visibility` value to `visible`.

The second time that I launch the application I fetch the info again from the server and I recreate the *Topic*.
Then I call the Realm method `add:update:` to update the object but this updates even the `visibility` property to `undefined` again.

I know that there is another method `create:value:update:` but this means that I have to create a big dictionary with all the values I want to update. My model objects are not so small, in some cases I have a lot of properties and the dictionary would be huge.
I don't like this approach, it is complicated to maintain.

Do you have any hint on how to handle a case like this?

A possibile way would be to create another Object (table) that has a relationship to *Topic* and one property `visibility` that is not overridden when I create the Topic again, but it sounds odd to create a table just for this thing.

Comment: Does your `Topic` object define a primary key property? If not, then each time you call `add:update:`, you'll actually be creating a new copy of the object in Realm.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably would be easier solved if you were passing a dictionary to `create:value:update:` since you could simply omit the `visibility` property, but as you said for size constraints, you're using a new instance of the model object that has `visibility` already set to a different value by the server response, then this can't really be helped. Realm cannot tell that you wish to keep this particular property and change the rest.

If you're using a primary key, then the quickest fix to this would be to simply fetch the original object via its primary key beforehand, make a note of its `visibility` property, and then re-set it after you've performed the update.

Breaking the `visibility` property off into its own object would work, but you'd most likely run into the same issue with the new object instance setting that property to `nil`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I ended up creating another model object to store that info and fetching it beforehand. It works, I'll see if it is better like this or if is better to just use the property and fetch it.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem with the way our service endpoint operates as well.  It provides a full entity view, along with smaller views of properties on that entity which I'd like to update the model when they are hit.
Example:

```
class User: Object {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var age: Int
  var average: Double
  likes: List<User>
}
```

One endpoint gets all 4 fields, another endpoint just gets `average` and `id`, and a 3rd only `likes` and `id`, however I'd like to create/update the model from any of them.
Now, I could use `create(value:update:)` on the raw JSON thats returned, however my model maps different keynames and does other transforming things (to Dates and other things as well) which I want preserved, so out goes the ability to just call `create(value:update:)` with the JSON dict.

We got around this by leveraging Reflection and a protocol called `Serializable`, that looks something like this:

```
protocol Serializable {
  func toDictionary() -> [String: Any]
}

extension Serializable {
  func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    var propertiesDictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for (propName, propValue) in mirror.children {
      guard let propName = propName else { continue }
      // Attempt to unwrap the value as AnyObject
      if let propValue: AnyObject = self.unwrap(propValue) as AnyObject? {
        switch propValue {
        case let serializablePropValue as Serializable:
          propertiesDictionary[propName] = serializablePropValue.toDictionary()
        case let arrayPropValue as [Serializable]:
          propertiesDictionary[propName] = Array(arrayPropValue.flatMap { $0.toDictionary() })
        case let data as Data:
          propertiesDictionary[propName] = data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        case _ as Bool: fallthrough
        case _ as Int: fallthrough
        case _ as Double: fallthrough
        case _ as Float: fallthrough
        default:
          propertiesDictionary[propName] = propValue
        }
      } else {
        // Couldn't treat as AnyObject, treat as Any
        switch propValue {
        case let arrayPropValue as [Serializable]:
          propertiesDictionary[propName] = arrayPropValue.flatMap { $0.toDictionary() }
        case let primative as Int8:   propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Int16:  propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Int32:  propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Int64:  propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as UInt8:  propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as UInt16: propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as UInt32: propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as UInt64: propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Float:  propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Double: propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Bool:   propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as String: propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Date:   propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        case let primative as Data:   propertiesDictionary[propName] = primative
        default: break
        }
      }
    }
    return propertiesDictionary
  }
  /// Unwraps 'any' object.
  /// See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type
  /// - parameter any: Any, Pretty clear what this is....
  /// - returns: The unwrapped object.
  private func unwrap(_ any: Any) -> Any? {
    let mi = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    guard let displayStyle = mi.displayStyle else { return any }
    switch displayStyle {
    case .optional:
      if mi.children.count == 0 {
        return nil
      }
      if let (_, some) = mi.children.first {
        return some
      } else {
        return nil
      }
    case .enum:
      let implicitTypes: [Any.Type] = [ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Int>.self,
                                       ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<String>.self,
                                       ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Double>.self,
                                       ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Bool>.self,
                                       ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Float>.self,
                                       ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Date>.self]
      if implicitTypes.contains(where: { $0 == mi.subjectType }) {
        if mi.children.count == 0 { return nil }
        if let (_, some) = mi.children.first {
          return some
        } else {
          return nil
        }
      }
      return any
    default: return any
    }
}
```

With this you can serialize your partially filled object, and then pass  with `create(value: obj.toDictionary(), update: true)`

Couple caveats to note:  `RealmOptional<T>`, `List<T>`, and `LinkingObjects<T>` are not handled here, you can add cases for explicit primitive types for `RealmOptional<T>`, a skip case for `LinkingObjectsBase`, and a skip case with custom handling for `ListBase` (reflection /does not/ play nicely with Lists :/)

Comment: Isn't it so that everyType can be ImlicitlyUnwrappedOptonal? Then using this array is not sufficient. Maybe you can change the if by: String(reflecting:type(of: any)).hasPrefix("Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<")

Comment: You could also use https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection and extend Object with the EVReflectable protocol. Then you will have a .toDictionary() that has more support for arrays, generics, nested objects and enheritance.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer yeah thats probably do-able, the IUO handling is hacky stop-gap fix due to Swift 3 breaking reflection on IUO's

Also, we opted to roll our own just so we could control what happens to RealmLists for instance, since handling them with generics/protocols doesn't work that well.
I'll check out that protocol to see if it maybe does better.

Comment: @apocalipse If you have any questions about EVReflection, then just ask them here: https://gitter.im/evermeer/EVReflection I only have done some basic tests with Realm with EVReflectable