# How to test if Any is actually an Optional? (Swift)

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm writing some debug code to which I need to pass a parameter of type Any. For printing purposes I'd like to unwrap the parameter value iff it's an optional, but I can't figure out how to test that - every syntactic form I can think of is rejected by the compiler. E.g.,

```
switch val {
case as Optional<Any>:
    .
    .
```

and a variety of `let` forms (including trying `.dynamicType`) aren't legitimate. Does anyone know how to actually do this? Overall, what I'm trying to accomplish is such that whether or not the value is an optional, I get the actual value into a string and not Optional.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/32516815/1187415.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I would not have found that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin is absolutely correct. From the linked post, modified slightly because I wanted a different return for nil:

```
func unwrap(any:Any, ifNil: Any = "nil") -> Any {

    let mi = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    if mi.displayStyle != .Optional {
        return any
    }

    if mi.children.count == 0 { return ifNil }
    let (_, some) = mi.children.first!
    return some

}
```