# Is there a way to use tabs to evenly space out description strings in Swift?

Tags: swift, debugging

Overriding the description variable of a custom class:

```
override var description : String {
        let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        let str:NSMutableString = NSMutableString()
        for (index, attr) in mirrored_object.children.enumerated() {
            if let property_name = attr.label as String! {
                //str.append(" Attr \(index): \(property_name) = \(attr.value)\n")
                str.append("\t\(property_name) = \t\t\(attr.value)\n")
            }
        }
        return str as String
    }
```

Produces output that looks like:

```
userID =        Optional(0)
username =          Optional("testuser")
email =         Optional("test@gmail.com")
```

Is there a way to set tabs in the output so that the attribute values line up nicely like this?

```
userID =        Optional(0)
username =      Optional("testuser")
email =         Optional("test@gmail.com")
```

Also, is there any way to get rid of or shorten the "Optional" part and just show the value?

Comment: For getting rid of the optional part, use null coalescing operator to avoid needing to unwrap it. So change \(attr.value) to \(attr.value ?? "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use tabs but use `padding(...)`:

```
var description : String {
    let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let childrenWithLabel = mirrored_object.children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let maxLen = childrenWithLabel.map { Int($0.label!.characters.count) }.max() ?? 0
    let lines = childrenWithLabel.map { $0.label!.padding(toLength: maxLen, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) + " = \($0.value)" }
    return lines.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

For a struct like

```
struct Foo: CustomStringConvertible
{
    let userID = 42
    let username = "Foo"
    let verylongpropertyname: String? = "Bar"
}
```

this produces

```
userID               = 42
username             = Foo
verylongpropertyname = Optional("Bar")
```

As for the "Optional" part, it's not as easy as totiG suggests because the value you get from the mirror is of type `Any`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/32780793#32780793).

**Update**

I overlooked that you wanted to have a slightly different format.

```
var description : String {
    let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let childrenWithLabel = mirrored_object.children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let separator = " = "
    let firstColumnWidth = (childrenWithLabel.map { Int($0.label!.characters.count) }.max() ?? 0) + separator.characters.count
    let lines = childrenWithLabel.map {
        ($0.label! + separator).padding(toLength: firstColumnWidth, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) + "\($0.value)"
    }
}
```

produces

```
userID =               42
username =             Foo
verylongpropertyname = Optional("Bar")
```

**Update 2**

To get rid of the "Optional" thing, please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/43323245#43323245).

If you use (from said answer) `unwrap()` or `unwrapUsingProtocol()` in `description` like this:

```
var description : String {
    let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let childrenWithLabel = mirrored_object.children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let separator = " = "
    let firstColumnWidth = (childrenWithLabel.map { Int($0.label!.characters.count) }.max() ?? 0) + separator.characters.count
    let lines = childrenWithLabel.map {
        ($0.label! + separator).padding(toLength: firstColumnWidth, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0) + "\(unwrap($0.value))"
    }
    return lines.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

this will produce

```
userID =               42
username =             Foo
verylongpropertyname = Bar
```

Comment: The unwrap solution in that link didn't work for me, but this answers the main question of formatting my description.

Comment: @GoldenJoe I added an answer myself to the question I linked to and a second update here, does this work for you now?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much! I would add that you must subclass NSObject and override description for this to work. Since I have your ear I'll point you to my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336724/how-can-i-nest-debug-output-in-swift

Comment: @GoldenJoe Either that or you make whatever you want to print `CustomStringConvertible`, like `struct Foo` above.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this method. It first calculates the max length of the property, and then uses that to pad the property names:

```
let maxPropertyLength: Int = mirrored_object.children.map { Int($0.label?.characters.count ?? 0) }.max() ?? 0
for attr in mirrored_object.children {
    if let propertyName = attr.label {
        str.append("\(propertyName.padding(toLength: maxPropertyLength + 2, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)) = \(attr.value)\n")
    }
}
return str as String
```