# How can I nest debug output in Swift?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have an object like:

```
class MyClass
{
   let a_number : Int?
   let a_string : String?
   let an_array_of_strings : Array<String>?
   let an_array_of_objs : Array<Any>?
}
```

How could I make it so that when I print this object to console, z is indented like so:

```
MyClass
a_number            = 4
a_string            = "hello"
an_array_of_strings = ["str1",
                      "str2",
                      "str3"]
an_array_of_objs    = [MyClass
                      a_number            = 5
                      a_string            = "world"
                      an_array_of_strings = nil
                      an_array_of_objs    = nil]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do that with a recursive function with an accumulator parameter for the indentation. It defaults to no indentation and is increased by the first column's width on each recursive call:

```
func describe<T>(_ x: T, indent: String = "") -> String
{
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: x)
    guard !mirror.children.isEmpty else { return x is String ?  "\"\(x)\"" : "\(x)" }

    switch mirror.displayStyle! {
    case .tuple:
        let descriptions = mirror.children.map { describe(unwrap($0.value), indent: indent) }
        return "(" + descriptions.joined(separator: ",\n\(indent)") + ")"
    case .collection:
        let descriptions = mirror.children.map { describe(unwrap($0.value), indent: indent) }
        return "[" + descriptions.joined(separator: ",\n\(indent)") + "]"
    case .dictionary:
        let descriptions = mirror.children.map { (child: Mirror.Child) -> String in
            let entryMirrors = Array(Mirror(reflecting: unwrap(child.value)).children)
            return describe(unwrap(entryMirrors[0].value), indent: indent) + ": "
                + describe(unwrap(entryMirrors[1].value))
        }
        return "[" + descriptions.joined(separator: ",\n\(indent)") + "]"
    case .set:
        let descriptions = mirror.children.map { describe(unwrap($0.value), indent: indent) }
        return "Set(" + descriptions.joined(separator: ",\n\(indent)") + ")"
    default:
        let childrenWithLabel = mirror.children.filter { $0.label != nil }
        let separator = " = "
        let firstColumnWidth = (childrenWithLabel.map { Int($0.label!.characters.count) }.max() ?? 0)
            + separator.characters.count
        let subindent = indent + String(repeating: " ", count: firstColumnWidth)

        let lines = childrenWithLabel.map {
            indent
            + ($0.label! + separator).padding(toLength: firstColumnWidth, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
            + describe(unwrap($0.value), indent: subindent)
        }
        return (["\(mirror.subjectType)"] + lines).joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

This function uses the `unwrap(_:)` function from [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989094/how-to-unwrap-an-optional-value-from-any-type/43323245#43323245)

```
func unwrap<T>(_ any: T) -> Any
{
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: any)
    guard mirror.displayStyle == .optional, let first = mirror.children.first else {
        return any
    }
    return first.value
}
```

When using `describe(_:)` like this (I made `MyClass` a struct so I can use the memberwise initializer):

```
struct MyClass: CustomStringConvertible
{
    let a_number : Int?
    let a_string : String?
    let an_array_of_strings : Array<String>?
    let an_array_of_objs : Array<Any>?

    var description: String { return describe(self) }
}

print(MyClass(a_number: 4, a_string: "hello",
              an_array_of_strings: ["str1", "str2", "str3"],
              an_array_of_objs: [
                  MyClass(a_number: 5, a_string: "world",
                          an_array_of_strings: nil, an_array_of_objs: nil)]))
```

then the output is

```
MyClass
a_number =            4
a_string =            "hello"
an_array_of_strings = ["str1",
                      "str2",
                      "str3"]
an_array_of_objs =    [MyClass
                      a_number =            5
                      a_string =            "world"
                      an_array_of_strings = nil
                      an_array_of_objs =    nil]
```

Please note that this is only tested with your specific example and some simple additions. I am also not happy about the forced unwrap of `mirror.displayStyle` but in my shallow testing this only ever happened when `mirror.children` is empty, which is covered by the preceding `guard`. If anybody has investigated this more closely, I'd love a comment. I haven't found anything in the documentation of `Mirror`.

And just like in [my answer to your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43271970/is-there-a-way-to-use-tabs-to-evenly-space-out-description-strings-in-swift/43274291#43274291) I mixed up where the `=` is supposed to be. Just the other way round this time, duh! :)

Comment: Actually I like the way you had the = indented originally so I went ahead and changed it. :)

Comment: I was testing this out, and I get some strange results for strings. They print out like: time_held   = Any
           timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate = 513703081.0

Comment: ^ I meant dates. Dates print out weird. My class also prints as "[Any" rather than "[MyClass"

Comment: Heh, I hoped that "only tested with your specific example" wouldn't work out so bad. I'll have a look into it (not at the computer right now). Could you in the meantime please add a comment with a snippet how exactly you are calling describe? Other than that, you just added a date property to MyClass?

Comment: @GoldenJoe I could not reproduce the "Any" issue for `Date` or `MyClass` values. Dates do print out as `Date\ntimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate = ...`, just like they do with `po` in lldb (`Date` is a `struct`). If you could give me a code sample, that might help. I also added handling the other display styles (tuple, dictionary, set).